# Summing integers in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

How do I use the Loop Summing Pattern to calculate and print the total score of all the games in this list of dictionaries? The Sum function is not allowed, nor is importing functions:

```
games = [
    {"Name": "UD", "Score": 27, "Away?": False},
    {"Name": "Clemson", "Score": 14, "Away?": True},
    {"Name": "Pitt", "Score": 32, "Away?": True},
]
```

I would suppose that there is some way of accessing it via a for loop?

```
for i in games: ......

for i in games["Score"]:
```

gets SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

I tried:

```
sum_hold = sum(d.get("Score", 0) for d in games)
```

but I am not allowed to use the sum function for the assignment

Comment: You know how the sum function works, right?  Just unravel your comprehension.  `for d in games:` / `mysum += d['Score']`.

Comment: `for i in games:` is the correct way to start it. Show what you wrote in `...`

Comment: When sorting out a syntax error, we need the exact code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Okay, so you know how to write a `for` loop. If you write `for i in games:`, according to what you already know, what will be the value of `i` each time through the loop? Can you see how to get a score value out of that `i`? Can you see how to use that in order to solve the problem? Did you try to re-read your textbook or your course notes, in order to understand what the assignment means by "the Loop Summing Pattern"?

Comment: Anyway, please read [ask] and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a list of dictionaries that you can iterate. Once you get a single game, the Score is easy to grab.

```
games = [
    {"Name": "UD", "Score": 27, "Away?": False},
    {"Name": "Clemson", "Score": 14, "Away?": True},
    {"Name": "Pitt", "Score": 32, "Away?": True},
]

total = 0
for game in games:
    total += game.get("Score", 0)

print(total)
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want to write it this way (same method Tim Roberts mentioned in the comment):

```py
games = [
{"Name": "UD", "Score": 27, "Away?": False},
{"Name": "Clemson", "Score": 14, "Away?": True},
{"Name": "Pitt", "Score": 32, "Away?": True},]

sum_hold = 0

for i in games:
  sum_hold += i['Score']

print(sum_hold)
```